# How to save a list of lxml.etree._ElementTree to file

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I'm running into an annoying problem with the lxml library and cant figure out how to get around it.

I have a list of lxml.etree._ElementTree tree's and a list of lxml.html.HtmlElement's which belong to those trees and have the corosponding paths stored in a list called paths

```
element_found = [True if len(tree.xpath(path)) > 0 else False for tree,path in zip(trees,paths)]
print(element_found.count(False)) # == 0
```

problem becomes when I try and save the paths and trees to later retrieve this state:

```
trees_to_save = [{'tree': lxml.etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)} for tree in trees]
t2sdf = pd.DataFrame(trees_to_save)
t2sdf.to_csv('trees.csv')

EncodeForamt = lxml.html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')

trees_from_file = pd.read_csv('trees.csv')
trees_from_file['tree'] = trees_from_file['tree'].apply(lambda x: etree.HTML(literal_eval(x),EncodeForamt).getroottree())
```

then the same test is ran:

```
element_found = [True if len(tree.xpath(path)) > 0 else False for tree,path in zip(trees_from_file,paths)]
print(element_found.count(False)) # == 6 (out of 12k)
```

Generally im trying to accomplish all paths being found, there is clearly a problem with either to/from string methods and how I'm saving the trees. I've tried various methods in the lxml library such as tree.write and instead of to string, instead of literal_eval just .encode('utf-8') to no avail, with and without pretty_print, tried etree.from_string() also same result for everything...

worryingly this throws XML syntax errors also:

```
trees = [etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(t)) for t in trees]
```

I'm at a bit of a loss of how to get these trees properly saved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to get this done after a while of trying everything I could find, needed to use parse instead of tostring:

```
trees_to_save = [{'tree': lxml.etree.tostring(tree,encoding='utf-8',method='html')} for tree in trees]
t2sdf = pd.DataFrame(trees_to_save)
t2sdf.to_csv('location_trees.csv')

trees_from_file = pd.read_csv('location_trees.csv')
EncodeForamt = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
trees_from_file['tree'] = trees_from_file['tree'].apply(lambda x: lxml.etree.parse(x,parser=EncodeForamt))
```